# Weinre JS API onload/ready event

Tags: node.js, weinre

I'm using Weinre to debug an iPad App and was looking for a JS callback from Weinre that signals when Weinre has finished loading and e.g. it's safe to use its `console` object in my code.

I looked through the docs and the `target-script.js` that hooks Weinre into my page but couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same problem, did you figured out a way?

Comment: @CaioToOn: Unfortunately no. Right now I'm waiting 500ms before using e.g. `console.log()` which works in my debug environment. As Weinre will be removed in production anyway I use this workaround until I find a solution that feels trustworthy ;)

Comment: Another approach is to put your init code into a function, and call this function from a remote console - this way you'll be sure the console is initailized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by "safe to use the `console`" object, you mean, when will writing to the `console` object start writing to the remote console window.  If so, that's a tough proposition, as your app might NEVER connect to a client debugger.  Or the client debugger might connect, then disconnect, then connect, ...  There would really need to be two events - `weinreConnected` and `weinreDisconnected`, or some such.

I didn't want to have to add new events to the system, but if there's a lot of interest, we can probably make it happen.  Feel free to [open a Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?pid=12312420&components=12316604&issuetype=2) for a new feature.